# How to export a list of dataframes in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list that consists of a large number of data frames, and every time R crashes I lose the variable and have to recreate it. The problem is that my list of data frames is pretty large and takes several hours to recreate.

Is there anyway to save/export this list so I can just load it into R at my convenience (without having to recreate it)?

Comment: `save()` for saving multiple R objects. `saveRDS()` for saving a single R object.

Comment: Try the soar package

Comment: ``save.image()`` for saving directly to working directory your entire workspace if you want your workflow data included.